# use of undeclared identifier 'k' that is declared

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, int, identifier

I'm newbie, would appreciate any help.

> use of undeclared identifier 'k'

```
void initBricks(GWindow window)
{
    // print bricks
    for(int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++);
    {
        // int I have problem with

        int b = k;
        //coordinats
        int x = 2;
        int y = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: for(int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++); <<<<<<<

Answer (score 6):

Look at the semicolon after the `for` loop:

```
for(int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++);
{
    // int I have problem with

    int b = k;
    //coordinats
    int x = 2;
    int y = 10
}
```

is the same as

```
for(int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++)   //<-- no semicolon here
{
}

{
    // int I have problem with

    int b = k;
    //coordinats
    int x = 2;
    int y = 10
}
```

`k` is only valid inside the block of the `for` loop, the next block does not
know about `k`.

You would have to write

```
for(int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++)   //<-- no semicolon here
{
    int b = k;
    //coordinats
    int x = 2;
    int y = 10
}
```

In C the scope of the variable is determined by the block (the lines of code in
the curly braces), you can have this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int x = 7;
    {
        int x = 9;
        printf("x = %d\n", x);
    }

    printf("x = %d\n", x);
}
```

and it would print

```
9
7
```

because there are two `x` variables. The `int x = 9` in the inner loop "overrides" the `x` of the
outer block. The inner loop `x` is a different variable as the outer block `x`,
but the inner loop `x` cease to exit when the inner loop ends. That's why you cannot access
variables from other blocks (unless an inner loop does not declare a variable
with the same name). This would for example generate a compile error:

```
int foo(void)
{
    {
        int x = 9;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

You would get an error like this:

```
a.c: In function ‘foo’:
a.c:30:12: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     return x;
            ^
a.c:30:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

This next code would compile

```
int foo(void)
{
    int x;
    {
        int x = 9;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

but you would get this warning

```
a.c: In function ‘foo’:
a.c:31:12: warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     return x;
            ^
```

Prior to C99 standard you could not write `for(int i = 0; ...`, you had to declare the
variable before the `for` loop. Nowadays most modern compiler use C99 as default, that's why you see a
lot of answers declaring the variable in `for()`. But the variable `i` would
be only visible in the `for` loop, so the same rules apply like in the examples
above. Note that this only works for `for` loop, doing `while(int c = getchar())` is not possible, you will get an error
from the compiler.

Also be aware of the semicolon, writing

```
if(cond);
while(cond);
for(...);
```

is the same as doing

```
if(cond)
{
}

while(cond)
{
}

for(...)
{
}
```

That's because the C grammar basically says, that after an `if`, `while`, `for`
you need either a statement or a block of statements. `;` is a valid statement
which does "nothing".

These is hard to find bugs in my opinion, because when reading the brain misses the `;` very often when you
look at the line.

Comment: If you downvote me, please leave a message saying why, so that I can fix the answer.